# How to determine if WPF window is open?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am trying to run a block of code when my WPF window is not open. Following code is not working please check it and let me know where I am doing wrong.

```cs
var window = IsWindowOpen<Window>(this.Title);
if(window)
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    // My code block                
}
```

```cs
public static bool IsWindowOpen<T>(string name = null) where T : Window
{
    var windows = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>();
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? 
        Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().Any() : 
        Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().Any(w => w.Name.Equals(name));
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with that code?

Comment: Its running but bool is false even though my window open...

Comment: I assume that the wpf window you are searching is part of the same application. What is the name of the class of that window?

Comment: Class name: frm_ChatForm and this.Title returns same frm_ChatForm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `Window.Title`, but then in your `IsWindowOpen` function you are trying to match `Window.Name`

Comment: Both title and name are same.

Comment: @ThiyaguRajendran paul is right. The name is probably empty. Just change `w.Name.Equals(name)`for `w.Title.Equals(name)`and it would work

Comment: @ThiyaguRajendran Anyway i would not use title as a way to find a window. I would try looking for its specific class type.

Comment: Thanks I will surely check it.